Cognitive science and project management?
I’m new to this field. I’m starting to realize just how theoretical stuff like managing a business is.
I think it’s very cool that the lean business plan / lean startup model was actually derived from work on the ontology of businesses. This reminds of another very widely used taxonomic system, the “five-factor model of personality” in psychology, statistically/algorithmically derived from lexical corpora (I wish I knew the exact algorithm).
I’m going to guess there is comparable work done in the field of project management and task management. Is there any “system” that’s a little empirically stronger than others, because it systematically analyzed the factors of “identifying, planning and completing tasks”, including cognitive ones and others?
I am interested in any such research, but particularly anything pertaining to “cognitive load”. I am currently trying to strike a balance between how powerful rigorous planning can be, yet sometimes, how mentally inefficient it can also be, and even sometimes obstructive to getting things done. Yet, without planning, there are sometimes other dire consequences.

As written, your question is too open-ended. You're basically asking about extant research in a given field, but that's really a search-type question rather than something that allows for canonical answers. Entire books are written on the subject of empirical systems control, so the scope of your question as posed is not suitable for PMSE.
